# how to store hwnd type data into a flat file and get it back into hwnd type variable?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

How to store and retrieve the hwnd type data into a flat file and get it back into hwnd type variable ?

I am writing as follows :

```
HWND g_hWndApp, g_hWndApp1;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("D:\\sri.txt");
myfile << g_hWndApp;
myfile.close();
int nCmdShow = 6;
ShowWindow(g_hWndApp,nCmdShow);
```

and reading as follows :

```
ifstream myReadFile;
char output[100];
myReadFile.open("D:\\sri.txt");
if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
       myReadFile >> output;
}
myReadFile.close();
g_hWndApp1 = (HWND) output;
```

however the values of `g_hWndApp` and `g_hWndApp1` are not the same, where am I going wrong ?

Note : I am using kinect to control maximize and minimize of a window based on Z depth so i need to know which window is minimized ,so that to maximize the same on certain condition..

Comment: Every time you create a window, it gets a new HWND. It will never be the same as previous. Why would you want to store HWND in a file?

Comment: What is your end goal? HWND is just a handle to the window, it is only useful until your program closes, so why would you write it to a file?

Comment: Why don't you read the input into a `HWND`, mirroring the output operation?

Comment: I am using kinect to control maximize and minimize of a window based on Z depth so i need to know which window is minimized ,so that to maximize the same on certain condition...

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to save a window handle to a file.

Comment: @ Raymond : How to maximize a window after minimizing it? I use nCmdShow =3 for Maximize and minimizing the window using nCmdShow = 6 using ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow). However, once I minimize the window, I cannot restore or maximize it.

This is because I cannot store the handler for the window that is minimized so that the same window can be maximized on certain condition? How to achieve the same ?

Comment: Store it in a variable. You don't need to save it in a file. Saving to a file creates all sorts of new problems, since window handles are not persistent.

Answer (score 1):

You're casting a pointer to a string into an integer. That obviously won't work.

You need to just read the integer from the file directly into a variable:

```
int hwnd;
myReadFile >> hwnd;
g_hWndApp1 = (HWND)hwnd;
```

Take note that the `HWND` of your window will not be the same when you close your program and restart it and recreate the window. There's really no point to storing it in a file, unless you are communicating with another program or something.

Comment: I am using kinect to control maximize and minimize of a window based on Z depth so i need to know which window is minimized ,so that to maximize the same on certain condition..

Answer (score 0):

To store arbitrary binary data one usually does this:

```
ofstream myfile; 
myfile.open ("D:\\sri.txt", std::ios_base::binary); 
myfile.write(&g_hWndApp, sizeof(g_hWndApp));
```

...

```
ifstream myReadFile("D:\\sri.txt", ios_base::binary); 
if (myReadFile.is_open()) { 
       myReadFile.read(&g_hWndApp1, sizeof(g_hWndApp1));
}
```